# Как получить позицию нажатого элемента списка ListView

Tags: android, android-studio

Вот код метода OnClick() в описании адаптера

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent;
    Context mContext;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    String title = viewHolder.txtTitle.getText().toString();


    Log.i("clicked",title);

    mContext = getContext();
    intent = new Intent(mContext, CafeCard.class);
    intent.putExtra("CAFE_TITLE", title);


    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Как получить позицию нажатого элемента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На `ListView` повесьте обработчик `OnItemClickListener`, где параметр `position` - позиция нажатого элемента.

Пример:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
        // Ваш код...
    }
});
```